# Hololens Emulator not Launching Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have Virtual Box installed on macbook pro , In Virtual Box I have windows 10 . I am trying to launch Hololens Emulator . It doesn't launch , shows some Hyper-V unable to launch error.[image: 1]]

Comment: Enable hyper v in bios

Comment: as mentioned, this will not work with VirtualBox, but it does work with Bootcamp

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will not work, you can not run Hyper V within another Hypervisor.  (in your case virtual box)  Hyper V requires Virtualization Extensions (AMD-V, VT-X) and Virtual Box does not emulate them, and most likely if it did it would be very slow.

Here is a discussion about this on the Virtual Boxforums: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is enabled virtualization in the mac os, and used bootcamp to load windows, and this will work.